# How to change the colour of a table row in javadoc in the javadoc comments

Tags: java, html, css, javadoc

I made an application that does security checks on java code automatically.

It generates javadoc comments for each field, constructor, methods etc. Depending on conditions within the code being checked, I want to change the colour of a table row in a table generated by javadoc.

So far I can add a column and change the colour of the row under that column like the picture below using [html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVfaV.png) (example of one of the fields conditions) in the javadoc comments.

[Current results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OsyV.png)

I'd like it to change the colour of the entire row.

Comment: include your current code

Answer (score 1):

The `<th>` tag defines a single header cell in an HTML table. Applying `bgcolor` attribute to it, will change the background color of that single cell.

If you would like to change the color of the entire row of cells, you can either apply `bgcolor` attribute to every single cell in that row, or a better solution would be to apply it to a table row `<tr>` tag.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th bgcolor="red">Example</th>
        <th bgcolor="red">Example</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Its worth noting that the `bgcolor` attribute is not supported in HTML5. You should use CSS instead.

```
<table>
    <tr style="background-color: red;">
        <th>Example</th>
        <th>Example</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped me understand html a bit. Unfortunately, it didn't solve my problem. The first suggestion you made adds to more cells to the table that javadoc creates initially, which is the one I'm trying to edit the colour off and the second didn't work at all unfortunately. I'm assuming its because javadoc is creating the html file and there is only so much you can change by adding html to the javadoc comments.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not that familiar with javadoc. My answer tells you what you would have to do in HTML to change the background of the table row. How to actually do it in java is something I am not familiar with. I assume you would have to edit the javadoc generator class, if that's even possible.